# Register the new user in Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is the function I have used to register the user into the Firebase database. Again and again, `else` part is getting executed (i.e. user is not created). Can I have an alternative code for that?

```
function registerUser(email, password){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user) {
            // User is created if will be automatically signed in
            console.log('created and signed in');
        } else {
            // No user created hence not signed in.
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `catch` means it failed....need to focus on `error` and use `then()` for the success

Comment: didn't get u....
can u be more specific please.

Comment: If `catch()` is triggered then `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` failed and you need to inspect the error object to find out why

Comment: getting errors...............
got strucked and confused.......
can u provide me some code please

Comment: I am getting the username and password but in the var user 
i am getting null

Comment: console.log(error) ... inspect that

Comment: The error shown - 



P
code
:
"auth/operation-not-allowed"
message
:
"The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."
__proto__
:
Error
I
:
()
constructor
:
(a,b)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: well there's the problem.

Comment: can you tell me the problem

Comment: read what it says....you are not set up properly in the project. The message is quite clear

Answer (score 0):

```
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('email@gmail.com', 'password')
            .then(function (firebaseUser) {
                console.log(firebaseUser.user);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Can you explain your code to the community by adding some description to your post ?